# Android Studio: Remove default header

Tags: android, android-studio

I am just beginning to learn Android Studio (version 2.0, running on Windows 7). When I create a new project (Empty Activity template) Android Studio places a header at the top of the project. How can I remove the header?

Here's a picture of the problem. I want to get rid of the 'My Greeting Card' header.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You have to simply navigate like below....

`app -> res -> values -> styles.xml`

Find `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` line.

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` line shows, how your activity will look like.

There are lots of **Themes** available. Just remove `DarkActionBar` it and press `Cntrl+Space` to explore another themes. In your case, you do not want `Header` which is called `ActionBar` in Android Terminology.

So, Just change theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and you are done.

To get more deeply about how the theming work and other courses of Android, Just try **Pluralsight**. Go to below link and get 6 months free subscription. It is very good website to learn any technology.

[Pluralsight 6 Months Subscription](https://absolute-sharepoint.com/2015/12/free-pluralsight-6-month-subscription.html)

Answer (score 3):

Well the answer is already given, but still i would like to add if you don't want any kind of actionbar on top of the activity simply do this.
go to your res->values->styles.xml and add these xml code

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <!-- Light Indigo -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#3949AB</item>
        <!-- Dark Indigo -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#00B0FF</item>
        <!-- Blue -->
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
</resources>
```

and reference the theme in the style on any activity you want, like below in the manifest using **android:theme=@style/AppTheme**.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can hide Toolbar using

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Where would you place the call to getActionBar?

Comment: after setContentView();

Comment: Doesn't work. I assume that's within the onCreate method.

Comment: you extend Activity? or AppCompatActivity?

Comment: I extend AppCompatActivity. By the way, when I say "I", this is code generated by Android Studio. I haven't touched it other than to add a line invoking getActionBar().hide(); as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

**For Newer Version**

app -> res -> values -> themes -> **themes.xml**

In that it also depends whether the phone is in night mode or not.

Then You have to modify both the files:

1. themes.xml
2. themes.xml (night)

with
**parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"**

Answer (score 0):

just Remove AppCompatActivity and extend it with only Activity

Comment: please elaborate yourself.